# Solve the problem using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, orthogonal-polynomials

If $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$ are integers, prove that : $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}|1+e^{in_1x}+...+e^{in_kx}|dx \leq \sqrt{k+1}$$

***my attempt*** : I want to solve the problem using [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) :

$$|z|^2 = z. \bar{z}$$
then
$$| \sum_{\kappa=0}^{k} e^{in_{\kappa}x}|^2 = (\sum_{\kappa = 0}^{k}e^{in_{\kappa}x}) (\sum_{\lambda = 0}^{k}e^{-in_{\lambda}x})$$

where $n_0=0$ and we need $n_i$ to be distinct nonzero integers

After that, how to show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}|1+e^{in_1x}+...+e^{in_kx}|dx \leq \sqrt{k+1}$$

Comment: I think the inequality is wrong since if you let $n_1=n_2=\cdots=n_k=0$, $LHS=k+1$>$RHS$.

Comment: do you have any hint to this problem ?

Comment: The inequality is wrong and so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is

$$\left|\int f(x){\overline {g(x)}}\,dx\right|^{2}\leq \int |f(x)|^{2}\,dx\cdot \int |g(x)|^{2}\,dx$$

which works for any range of integration. Setting $f(x)=1+e^{in_1x}+\dots+e^{in_kx}$ and $g(x)=f(x)/|f(x)|$ (or $1$ if $f(x)=0$) gives

$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)|\,dx\right)^{2}\leq \int_0^{2\pi}  |f(x)|^{2}\,dx\cdot \int_0^{2\pi}  1\,dx$$

The $|f(x)|^2=f(x)\overline{f(x)}$ is just a linear combination of exponentials, so can be easily evaluated as $2\pi(k+1)$ using the assumption that $0,n_1,\dots,n_k$ are distinct. This gives the desired bound $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x)|\,dx\leq\sqrt{k+1}$.

Comment: I think you are missing a condition in "so can be easily evaluated as [...]". Perhaps, all integers being distinct.

Comment: @ClementC: yes, I am using exactly that assumption, which was buried in the question

Comment: Yes - mentioning it explicitly would be good, since, as you say, it's buried in the original question (and is not immediately clear where you rely on it).

Comment: @ClementC: done